# Website unresponsive - group query not found

Tags: wordpress

I set up a new website recently with Wordpress and now the website is unresponsive for some reason. The error message I am receiving is below.

The7\Adapters\Elementor\Widgets\The7_Elementor_Elements_Woocommerce_Carousel_Widget::add_group_control: Group "query-group" not found.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Website: [www.santaslittleworld.com](http://www.santaslittleworld.com)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your theme is broken, you need to log into wp-admin and change the theme to get your front-end working again. Then submit a ticket to the relevant support team.

We can do absolutely nothing with the error text posted above.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your reply and help. I will do as you mentioned. Thanks